# Quantum vs Classical estimation using Fisher Information

Tags: quantum-information, estimation, statistics

Is it possible to have a different estimated value of a parameter by [Classical Fisher Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) (CFI) compared to [Quantum Fisher Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fisher_information) (QFI)?

Say, for example, I am plotting, $\mathcal{F_{\nu}} $, Fisher Information for parameter $\nu$ with respect to $\nu$. When estimating $\nu$ using CFI I get a peak in plot at, say, $\nu = 1.03$ and when estimating using QFI the peak is at $\nu = 1.06$. Is it ever possible?

Using [Cramer-Rao Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound), I think that only the estimation precision should be different. For example, estimation using QFI could be 6 orders of magnitude more precise compared to CFI if QFI $\sim 10^{30}$ whereas CFI $\sim 10^{24}$ because the variance is now 6 orders of magnitude less for QFI compared to CFI using the Cramer-Rao Bound. Whatever this be, I think the parameter's estimated value should be same.

Can anyone please give arguments in support or against the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key difference between the QFI and CFI is that CFI depends on the measurement you use.

> Is it possible to have a different estimated value of a parameter

Neither of these are estimators, they give you bounds on your estimate so I'm not 100% what you mean here. You would use say, maximum likelihood estimation if you want to actually estimate some parameter. Both QFI/CFI have nothing to do with the actual estimate you get from an estimation procedure.

If it is only one parameter you are interested in then there exists a measurement such that the CFI and QFI are equal. This is the optimal measurement to use. If it is a multi-parameter problem then this is not necessarily the case.

$10^{30}$ is a pretty big QFI but not completely outside the realms of possibility! If you want to supply some more details of the system you're interested in I could give a more detailed response.

Comment: Thank you :). That is enough.